# Update git staged file to be a rename instead of a deleted and new file

Tags: git

If I use `git mv` then it records correctly the rename :

```
renamed:    oldname -> newname
```

But if I am just moving some files around and then `git add` they become unlinked:

```
deleted:    oldname
new file:   newname
```

Is there was a simple way to update the staged index, to change the deleted/new-file to a rename?

`git version 2.25.0`

Comment: What's your git version?

Comment: Not really. Git actually doesn't care.

Comment: Don't give them hope, @RomainValeri :-D For real, that's a user-level thing, not something that git tracks when committing.

Comment: as far as I know your have to `git reset` the change and then do `git mv`, if you really care about how things goes in git, but that's not much of different.

Comment: To be honest, I tried it out with a simple move without `git mv`, then adding everything, and the file got detected as renamed. Thus my question about version, I was unsure whether older versions did that also. But I guess you're right :-)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? A set of commands that show how `mv` created this state, including a `git status` at the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+detect+rename

Comment: "git doesn't care" but I do! "not something that git tracks"/"but that's not much of different" if moved git tracks changes in the files regardless of the rename.

Comment: The question about git detecting automatically is fine on its own, this question is more about if its not detected => then what? Because currently, I do a dance of reset/mv/co/git-mv/ci!